# Referencing Schema Name as Variable in Oracle Procedure

Tags: oracle, variables, schema

Is there a way to set schema name as variable in oracle procedure?

create or replace procedure test is
v_schema varchar2(30);

begin

insert into v_schema.tab_a ( a, b)
select (a, b) from xyz;

end;
/

Thanks

Comment: only using dynamic sql: execute immediate 'insert into '||v_schema'.tab_a.....';

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to resort to dynamic SQL

```
create or replace procedure test 
is 
  v_schema varchar2(30);
  v_sql    varchar2(1000);
begin
   v_sql := 'insert into ' || v_schema || '.tab_a( a, b ) ' ||
               'select a, b from xyz';
   dbms_output.put_line( 'About to execute the statement ' || v_sql );
   execute immediate v_sql;
end;
```

A couple of points

1. You almost certainly want to build the SQL statement in a local variable that you can print out and/or log before executing it.  Otherwise, when there are syntax errors, you're going to have a much harder time debugging.
2. You almost never want to resort to dynamic SQL in the first place.  The fact that you have a procedure where you know you want to insert all the rows from `xyz` into a table named `tab_a` but you don't know which schema that table is in is a red flag.  That's unusual and often indicates a problem with your design.  Very, very occasionally dynamic SQL is a wonderful tool when you need extra flexibility.  But more often than not when you're thinking about a problem and dynamic SQL is the answer you want to reconsider the problem.

Comment: Thanks. The problem with insert statements is that they are too long and have quotes and  ( etcc. which are nightmare to debug.  Is  there a way to make the partial statement meaning   v_sql :='insert into || v_schema || ' string_1'; I tried this but getting errors.

Comment: @RMAN - Sorry, I'm not understanding what a "partial statement" is in this context.  One of the reasons that you want to put the statement in a local variable is so you can debug the inevitable syntax errors if you are trying to dynamically generate a statement of any length.  You can (and should) use bind variables wherever you can to avoid having to escape strings.  You may also benefit from using the q quoting syntax, i.e. `v_sql := q'{insert into foo( a, b ) select 'bar', 'baz' from dual}'` rather than trying to correctly escape every single quote.